# LWC not available to add on home page

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have deployed one lightning web component to my org and trying to add it on home using lightning app builder. But it is not available to add. I checked everything and couldn’t find the reason. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Did you add home page target in xml `lightning__HomePage` ? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_app_builder

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set isExposed to true and also set proper targets in xml of your lwc. You can refer below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
  <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```